# How to open the terminal with specific command already run? Best at Unity Launcher!

Tags: unity, command-line, 14.04, launcher, gnome-terminal

I know how to add a command to the `Unity Launcher`, but don't know **how to have automatically opened terminal for the command**.

Especially needed when `sudo` command needs password or command result should be seen.

Comment: `Terminal=true`  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to open a terminal or uxterm with already running a command:

```
uxterm -e <command>
```

Or

```
gnome-terminal -x <command>
```

For multiple commands to be already run:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "<command1>; <command2>; <command3>"
```

Comment: `gnome-terminal -e "command"` works for me. How can I keep the terminal open after execution of command(s) without changing the `profile`?

Comment: use `exec $SHELL` as the last command

Comment: and for unity (since ubuntu 17.10)?